# Transparent Background in CCGLSurfaceView / CCLayer ( cocos2d-android )?

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

How to make transparent Background in CCGLSurfaceView / CCLayer ( cocos2d-android ) ?

I tried to change the superclass to CCColorLayer and set the color to `ccColor4B.ccc4(0,0,0,0)`, but didn't work.

Also, I tried to set the background color to `android.R.color.transparent`, but it is still opaque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCLayer should be transparent [no background] by default
you should have a CCScene behind it with a background that will show, like this

```
public MainScene{
    super();
    CCSprite bg = CCSprite.sprite("MainBG-gl.png", true);
    CGSize screen = CCDirector.sharedDirector().winSize();
    bg.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(screen.width / 2, screen.height / 2));
    addChild(bg);
    layer = new MainLayer();
    addChild(layer);}
```

that'd be the constructor of your CCScene where MainLayer is your CCLayer that you wanna use [bg is the background obviously]

Comment: What is the difference of using `CCLayer` and `CCLayerColor` with transparent color in constructor?